# getting double border in IE10 in CKEditor,how to remove double border from IE10 inside CKEditor

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, ckeditor

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 1px;
}

table>tbody>tr>td{
        display: table-cell;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
}
```

using above code IE showing Double border 
[image]

when Chrome showing table with single border
[image]

Comment: it's shows only one border: http://jsfiddle.net/avkoLc85/

Comment: acctually i am using it inside CKEditor

Comment: Hi Ezhil-UI Develope Thanks for reply  your fiddle not showing outside border which i needed